# minutes.sty (1.8d) stopped working (in texlive 2014)

Tags: errors

Up until recently minutes.sty worked like it should. But now the \topic{} macro throws errors like this:

```
\topic{A}

! Extra \else.
\stc@sect ...csname the#1\endcsname }\fi #7}\else 
                                              \def \@svsechd {#6\hskip #...
```

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{minutes}
\begin{document}
\begin{Protokoll}{X}
\topic{A} % if you comment this line. It works.
\end{Protokoll}
\end{document}
```

less minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,german,twoside,10pt]{scrartcl}%{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[]{minutes}

\begin{document}
\begin{Protokoll}{X}
\untertitel{Y}
\sitzungsdatum{Z}
\sitzungsort{XXX}
\teilnehmer{MR.X}
\fehlend[ne]{ne}
\sitzungsbeginn{20:00}
\sitzungsende{21:19}
\protokollant{G}
\moderation{H}
\maketitle
\topic{A}  % just the same as above
\end{Protokoll}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Additional info:

- KOMA-Script v3.12
- keyval.sty [2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)]
- multicol.sty [2014/08/24 v1.8g  multicolumn formatting (FMi)]
- that's all from the current stable install of Texlive 2014 on Sabayon Linux

So the outdated version of KOMA is the most likely cause. I'll check how I can update it to the latest version and report back.

EDIT: Putting KOMA script V3.15 in /usr/local/share/texmf and running texhash fixed the problem for me. This solves my question.

Comment: I do not get that error (with texlive 2014) i get `! Package minutes.sty Error: no output of title.`

Comment: @Jack: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My example below worked on a quite actual TeX-Live 2014 installation (with online update).
I get the same error as you on an older TeX-Live 2014 installation.

Can you check the version of the following packages:

- koma-script (working: v3.14, not working: v3.12)
- keyval.sty (same version number v1.15, but once 2014/10/28 vs 2014/05/08
- multicol.sty (v1.8i vs. v1.8e)

---

At least there is a missing `\maketitle` before you start the minutes:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{minutes}
\begin{document}
\begin{Protokoll}{X}
\maketitle %<=== Here
\topic{A} % if you comment this line. It works.

\end{Protokoll}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

I'm not sure if this is your problem, because I get another error with your example. I get:

```
! Package minutes.sty Error: no output of title.

See the minutes.sty package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \topic{A}
            % if you comment this line. It works.
?
```

Background:
Inside the minutes (alias Protokoll) you can define location, minutetaker ...
This data are printed as a header at the start of the minutes (depending on your settings with different layout).

With `\maketitle` you define the end of the minutes header and start with the content. If you never call the `\maketitle`-makro inside the minutes, then you get an error.

Some other hints:

- minutes.sty uses babel - so I would recommend to define the language you use.

Comment: That example of yours gives the same extra \else error on my system.

Comment: This example is OK on my system. Perhaps you can say more on the topics: for example why did `minutes` report that error? and why `\maketitle` makes it works. Also I guess one would need to update packages to avoid the `extra \else`-error. Would you like to try to confirm it to improve your answer? (because this was flagged as low-quality.)

Comment: @Jack I had the possibility to check on an older TeXLive 2014 installation and got the same error. See my adapted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it might not be crystal clear by the previous answer, I give this answer as well:

An outdated version (v3.12) of KOMA script is the most likely cause.

If you cannot update this package by `tlmgr` to the latest version, you can put the contents of the KOMA script (v3.15) .zip file in `/usr/local/share/texmf` and run `texhash`.

The error should be gone now.